# Ordinary taks - complex solution

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have some users (C1, C2, C3, etc.) who handles products (aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, etc.) in differents stores (St1, St2, St3, St4, etc.).
Every user in the list wants to know in which store which products they can handle cheaper.
How looks out the tables and how looks out the queries if user want get at least the following 3 things (one at the time):

> 1- Get own list of products. Exemple:
>   Pr. St1 St2 St3 St4
>   aa $20 $12 $19 $22
>   bb $31 $44 $38 $44
>   cc $18 $12 $19 $22
>   dd $36 $44 $38 $44
>   ee $15 $12 $19 $22

> 2- Get a list of lowest prices (but greather than 0) and see how much he/she save if he/she handles the same products on others stores. Exemple:
>   Pr.   St4 St1 St3 St2
>   bb $23 $27 $26 $28
>   ee $14 $15 $15 $20
>   hh $36 $38 $40 $37
>   Sum $73 $80 $81 $85
>   Count products 3.
>
> ---
>
> Pr.  St2 St1 St3 St4
>   aa  $32 $33 $38 $36
>   cc  $21 $29 $27 $25
>   ff  $13 $14 $17 $20
>   Sum $66 $76 $82 $81
>   Count products 3.

> 3- Get a list of products which has cero price in each store. Exemple:
>   Pr. St1 St2 St3 St4
>   kk  $00 $12 $19 $22
>   ii  $00 $44 $38 $44
>
> Pr. St2 St1 St3 St4
>   ll  $00 $21 $52 $20
>   mm  $00 $13 $17 $15

A primitive not good solution:

CREATE TABLE `usrs` (
    `idc` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `stores` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `pwd` VARBINARY(72) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idc`)
)
COMMENT='Customers'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE `stores` (
    `ids` INT NOT NULL,
    `nm` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ids`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `idp` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `prod` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `st1` MEDIUMINT(9) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `st2` MEDIUMINT(9) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `st3` MEDIUMINT(9) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `st4` MEDIUMINT(9) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`idp`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (aa,14,20,13,17);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (bb,33,29,38,33);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (cc,19,20,00,21);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (dd,22,29,25,33);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (ee,30,00,35,29);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (ff,10,14,11,13);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (gg,00,00,00,00);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (hh,16,22,30,10);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (ii,23,34,34,26);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (jj,41,32,39,41);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (kk,25,29,26,19);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (ll,24,27,10,24);
INSERT INTO products (prod,st1,st2,st3,st4) VALUES (mm,29,41,37,36);

I don't know how all the tables can looks like when count of stores are more than 2 and count of users are more than 1.
In my solution I have to manually change the tables when users or stores increases. I understand here needs a relationship between tables, but I don't find out it. Bad, very bad ...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry Juan, it is not clear from the data what the relationship to customer is?
Do products have the same price for all customers?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your solution such that you had a list of prices connecting stores to products.

A price would be a tuple of Product, Store, and Price.

Then, you could select with a left join on this table. The where clause could have a specified store id, a price requirement, and/or product id.

**Example:**

I have modified the names of your tables for better clarity. Examples tested on MariaDB.

First, the models I will use:

```
CREATE TABLE `stores` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `prices` (
    `product_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `store_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT productIdToStoreID UNIQUE (product_id, store_id)
);
```

Here is how I would populate the database

```
INSERT INTO stores (id, name) VALUES (10, "Foo's Fun");
INSERT INTO stores (id, name) VALUES (20, "Bar's Barn");

INSERT INTO products (id, name) VALUES (10, "0xC0C0C01A");
INSERT INTO products (id, name) VALUES (20, "0xDEADBEEF");

INSERT INTO prices (product_id, store_id, price) VALUES (10, 10, 1.50);
INSERT INTO prices (product_id, store_id, price) VALUES (10, 20, 1.60);

INSERT INTO prices (product_id, store_id, price) VALUES (20, 10, 40);
INSERT INTO prices (product_id, store_id, price) VALUES (20, 20, 35);
```

Here are some starting points are queries you could write:

```
SELECT store_id, price FROM prices WHERE product_id = 10; -- All prices for product with id 10
SELECT store_id, price FROM prices WHERE product_id = 10 ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1; -- Get Cheapest Price and Store for product 10

SELECT stores.name, price FROM prices LEFT JOIN stores ON (stores.id = store_id) WHERE product_id = 10 ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1; -- Get the Store name and price.
```

**Motivation:**

We need a way that can relate n stores, m products. (Not sure where users go here). We need a data structure that can hold:

1. If a store has a item (conversely, if a product is in a store). We can see that this is a many to many relationship. SQL databases tend to be really optimized for this type of relationship.
2. The price of a product at a store.

Thus, we create a table that links a product to a store uniquely, with the extra metadata of the price.

As you pointed out, the alternative to this is a table that contains all of the stores as columns. However, this does not scale well at all as in order to add, remove, or change the name of a store would be a O(n) update. In a production environment, this would be detrimental as this would likely lock the database. but I digress.

This solution solves this issue by allowing the store list and product list to be decoupled from the actual products. If a price exists at a store for a product, there is a row. This means that the space complexity is at worst O(n), but in reality would be much less as not all stores would have all products.

Comment: Sorry Juan, it is not clear from the data what the relationship to customer is?
Do products have the same price for all customers?

Comment: Chris: thank you for answer. It seems I don't explain my self good enough, it's becouse you missunderstood the question. Supouse you are a user that want to know how much cost every product in one list in differents stores AND supouse yours friends want to know that too (same list of products). You get a list of users, a list of stores and a list of products. Do you get it now? Every user want to know (after update a prices of the products) in which store which products are cheaper. It's about where I (and others) can handle cheaper. Thanks again.

Comment: @N.w let me see if I understand you. You are saying that each user has a particular list of stores that they can visit. You are trying to see which user can get a list of products for least amount of money?

Comment: @Jacob: Thank you for answer. I don't know what needs, may be it needs a redundance. Your question gave me the following idea:
TABLE users (idusr, name),
TABLE prods(idpro, prds),
TABLE stores(idst, nams) and
TABLE prices(id, lusr, lpro, lstr, price) with CONSTRAINT `FKuser` FOREIGN KEY (`lusr`) REFERENCES `usrs` (`idusr`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `FKprod` FOREIGN KEY (`lpro`) REFERENCES `prods` (`idnr`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `FKstr` FOREIGN KEY (`lstr`) REFERENCES `stores` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION).

Comment: @Jacob (continue): Its very important to check (mark) permanent wich stores from the list each user want to handle from: I tried it with a fieldt in user's table, e.g. string St2-St4-St5 means that this user allways get list of prices from store 2, 4 and 5 only. Other user that checked Store 1 and 5 get prices from those stores only, etc. Do you think this can works? If it works, how looks like the queries from my original question? Jacob: answer to your second question is yes. Thanks again

Comment: @N.w I would avoid storing what stores users have access to in a string. Instead you could store it in another linking table as well. The rational behind this is that we want to be able to quickly iterate over the information, and I don't think there is a good way to do that. What I would suggest would be to create another table that connects users to stores. Then with a single query it would be possible to get the lowest price of all the stores a user has access to.

Comment: @Jacob: You are right, I see it now. Do you can show me with an exemple, please?

Comment: @N.w i don't want to make solve the entire problem for you, but where is the table structure I would suggest. Think about the queries that you could make with these relationships. `CREATE TABLE users ( 
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    pwd VARBINARY(72) NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_assessable_stores ( 
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    store_id INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT userIdToStoreId UNIQUE (user_id, store_id)
);`

Comment: @Jacob: I can do not much with just users and stores tables, as user I need in wich store wich products are cheaper. For exemple:  list of products wich are cheaper in store 1, plus list of products wich are cheaper in store 2, and soon. Sorry, but with 2 tables (users and store) I don't get that. Or I don't understand your idea ...

Comment: These two tables would be used in addition to my previous answer. The queries that I have provided could be easily modified to filter based on if that store exists in the users available store list. I do not want to solve the entire problem for you, but I will suggest combining all 5 tables together with some sample data and seeing what you can do. Most of database design is developing fast and efficient ways of representing information, but the most important part of that is figuring out how to query it. Good luck, but give it a go and see what you can retrieve.